# TinyMCE 5: xhtmlxtras controls/buttons missing

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5, tinymce-plugins

In TinyMCE 3 there used to be the plugin "**xhtmlxtras controls/buttons**" providing an option to add/edit common element attributes such as id, lang etc. (found here: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-3x/reference/TinyMCE3x@Plugins/Plugin3x@xhtmlxtras/). I cannot find this, or a similar option in TinyMCE 5. Has this been removed, or renamed?

**Or, if asked in a different way:**
How can one edit the "id" attribute of (let's say) an h2 heading in TinyMCE 5, without entering the "code" mode?